# Why Applying scale to my armature moves its position?

Tags: objects, armature, transforms, scale

I think applying scale means changes the Object data dimensions and makes object scale to 1 but why its moving my armature?

[image]

[image]

No Animations attached and no delta transformations present also.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your armature has currently a pose, once you've applied the scale, go in *Pose* mode and reset the pose (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>) and the armature will be back to its default position.

You've given your armature a pose, poses take the bones position in local space into account, if you apply the scale it changes the distances.

Comment: Shit I thought its Armature their default positions and didn't thought about resetting the transform in pose mode. Dumb mistake from my side. 
thanks for help!